# Find a file in Library Documents

Tags: search, search-scope

I must give a search box to the Library Documents. I do it by the filters, and everything goes right, before I put the files into the folders. Does anyone know any of method which goes to folders, and there searching too? The version is SharePoint 2013.

I want to search at folders too, not only in files.

Comment: Could you pls explain your question more clearly? Exactly what you need... Do you mean your searching can be done in folders too?

Comment: Yes, Y want to search by folders too, not only by.